# Why does a man use 'yourself' but not 'you'?

Tags: grammar

Why does a man use 'yourself' but not 'you'?

> I take an interest in people like **yourself**. Creative people.

from Pawn Sacrifice film about Bobby Fischer

Comment: both are acceptable, *yourself* is more colloquial, I guess

Comment: @Andrew Tobilko: It's nothing to do with "colloquial" - it's just a [sometimes possible] way of adding "emphasis", as per the answer below. But idiomatically it's not *always* "acceptable" - Google Books has over 700 instances of [*I hate people like **you***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I+hate+people+like+you%22), but not a single one of [*I hate people like **yourself***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I+hate+people+like+yourself%22). Whereas there are 165 hits for *I **admire** people like yourself* (against 456 hits for the non-reflexive form).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **[yourself](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/yourself)** (pronoun): 2. You personally (used to emphasize the person being addressed)

There is little difference in meaning between "you" and "yourself" in this context.  "Yourself" has slightly more emphasis, and suggests the speaker takes a *special* interest in the person being addressed.

[Some additional information on when to use "myself" and "yourself"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/when-to-use-myself-and-yourself)

Side note:  Referring to individuals as "a man" is an odd phrasing.  Instead you would say, as a hypothetical:

> Why would **someone** say ..?

or referencing an actual quote:

> Why does **this person** say ..?

Or refer to them by name/title:

> Why does **the author** say ..?

Which is not to say that "a man" is *wrong*.  It just means, specifically, "a personal of the male gender" rather than "some unspecified person".  As such, it's more likely to be used in a hypothetical:

> Why would **a man** suddenly quit his job, sell his house, and move to Tahiti to paint native women?

If you are talking about an actual quote or incident, use something like "that man" instead:

> Why did **that man** say that he was going to quit his job, sell his house, and move to Tahiti to paint native women?

Comment: I was interested to discover that apparently *every single one* of the 700+ hits in Google Books for ***I admire people like yourself*** (as per my comment under the actual question) turns out to be followed by a ***who-*** clause (as do nearly half of all the hits for the "non-reflexive" version). So we could say that one *big* reason for using the reflexive form is *when it represents the **subject** of a following clause*.